# chef client run in aws bootup script not getting registered in chef server

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

We have used below command to run on booting aws machine. It ran chef client and software is installed. But i am not able to find server in chef console when i searched with vm ip address.

chef-client -r 'role[test]'

Can some one explain chef-client -r option works

Answer (score 0):

The `-r` flag runs chef-client as normal but replaces the run-list coming from the Chef Server with the one specified on the command line. The two likely reasons for your confusion are either that chef-client is hitting an error which prevents the node data from being saved back to the server, or the way you are searching isn't correct. If you are looking for `ipaddress:1.2.3.4`, make sure you are using the private IP address (I think).

Comment: I actually created machine from amazon cloudformation with script. In machine softwares are installed and client.pem is created. I also searched with private ip address but i am still not able to get why i am not able to list in chef server.

Comment: Okay, so then more likely the initial run isn't succeeding. Enable logging to a file and check that file for an error message. Cloud-init unfortunately doesn't expose errors up to other pieces of the provisioning system.

Comment: Looks like chef client not completed its task totally. When i checked in event logs, chef client execution is not completed. This might be causing the issue.

Comment: Indeed, Chef must complete successfully to save its data back to the Chef Server.